# How to add a edges between component of a graph in igraph R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, greedy, connected-components

I have a graph containing `4 components`. Now, I want to add an edge among `all components` based on the `size of the membership`.

For example, the following graph contains `4 components`.

[image]

First, I will connect `all components with only one edge and take the edge randomly`. I can do it using this code

```
graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(g, directed = FALSE)
E(graph1)$weight <- g$new_ssp
cl <- components(graph1)

graph2 <- with(
  stack(membership(cl)),
  add.edges(
    graph1,
    c(combn(sapply(split(ind, values), sample, size = 1), 2)),
    weight = runif(choose(cl$no, 2))
  )
)
```

Secondly, now, I want to add an edge between `component-1 and component-2`. I want to add an edge between `2 components` but `rest of the component will be present in the new graph from the previous graph`.

Like, after adding an edge between `component-1 and component-2`, the new graph will contain `3 component 1st (component-1 and component-2 as a 1 component because we added 1 edge), 2nd (component-3 from the main graph), and 3rd (component-4 from the main graph)`. I can do it using this code

```
dg <- decompose.graph(graph1)
graph3 <- (dg[[1]] %u% dg[[2]])

component_subgraph_1 <- components(graph3)

graph2 <- with(
  stack(membership(component_subgraph_1)),
  add.edges(
    graph1,
    c(combn(sapply(split(ind, values), sample, size = 1), 2)),
    weight = 0.01))
```

Figure:
[image]

Same for all combinations. Such as, `component-1 and component-3`, and `component-1 and component-4`, and `component-2 and component-3`, and `component-2 and component-4`, and `component-3 and component-4`.

**But, this is not feasible to write the code and change manually `dg[[1]]`, `dg[[2]]`, and so on. Moreover, my actual dataset contains a lot of components. So, in reality, this is impossible.
Any idea, how can I do this automatically?**

Actually, I have a scoring function (like the shortest path). So, I want to check the score after `adding all components`, or `after adding only 2 components`, `after adding only 3 components`, and `so on`! Something like `greedy algorithms`.

Reproducible Data:

```
g <- structure(list(query = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                   5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ID_00104", 
                                                                                                       "ID_00136", "ID_00169", "ID_00178", "ID_00180"), class = "factor"), 
               target = structure(c(16L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 
                                    13L, 15L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 17L, 18L
               ), .Label = c("ID_00169", "ID_00288", "ID_00324", "ID_00394", 
                             "ID_00663", "ID_00790", "ID_00846", "ID_00860", "ID_00910", "ID_00959", 
                             "ID_01013", "ID_01047", "ID_01130", "ID_01222", "ID_01260", "ID_06663", 
                             "ID_06781", "ID_06786", "ID_06791", "ID_09099"), class = "factor"), 
               new_ssp = c(0.654172560113154, 0.919096895578551, 0.925821596244131, 
                           0.860406091370558, 0.746376811594203, 0.767195767195767, 
                           0.830379746835443, 0.661577608142494, 0.707520891364902, 
                           0.908193484698914, 0.657118786857624, 0.687664041994751, 
                           0.68586387434555, 0.874513618677043, 0.836646499567848, 0.618361836183618, 
                           0.684163701067616, 0.914728682170543, 0.876297577854671, 
                           0.732707087959009, 0.773116438356164)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                 -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually close to what you want already. Perhaps the code below could help you

```
out <- with(
  stack(membership(cl)),
  lapply(
    combn(split(ind, values), 2, simplify = FALSE),
    function(x) {
      add.edges(
        graph1,
        c(combn(sapply(x, sample, size = 1), 2)),
        weight = 0.01
      )
    }
  )
)
```

and then you can run

```
sapply(out, plot)
```

to visualize all the combinations.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't express how grateful I am. However, how can I get the graph (separately one by one)? As I said in the question (I have a scoring method, actually a chunk of code and I am taking the graph data from a dataframe) and I need to pass the graph 1 by 1 to the scoring method. In your code `combn(split(ind, values), 2, simplify = FALSE),` here `2` means `randomly 2 graphs`?

Comment: @Akib62 All the graph after combinations are save in list `out`. If you need to use pass the graph to your scoring function, maybe you can try something like `lapply(out,function(x) scoring(x,...))`. Besides, you got the point of `combn`.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, when I run the code `sapply(out, plot)` I got only 1 graph and when I run again I am getting 1 graph. Does it mean, you ran the code 6 times and you received 6 graphs individually?

Comment: @Akib62 If you are using RStudio, you will see 6 plots. Otherwise, you can try `for` loops to give all plots.

Comment: I am using RStudio but getting only one graph at a time. Need another guidance from you, my dataset is very large (the dataset contains 1,408,064 edges) and the size of the dataset app. 300MB. The dataset contains almost more than 200 components. What do you think, is it feasible to implement the idea (taking 1 graph and finding score using a loop) in terms of computation power, memory, and as a idea? Or I am going the wrong track?

Comment: @Akib62 There is a left/right arrow under `plots` tab in RStudio, and you press it to see all plots. I have no idea if this solution can scale up to a huge dataset as your real dataset. You can try but I guess it will take some longer time.

Comment: would you mind to chek this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69803480/how-to-add-an-edge-between-components-of-a-graph-based-on-the-maximum-degree-of)

Comment: @0Knowledge yes, see my answer in your post