# How to add an edge between components of a graph based on the maximum degree of a node of the component

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a graph that contains 4 components of different cluster sizes.
[image: Main Graph]

I can see the details using the below code

```
cl <- components(graph1)
```

The details are looks like

```
$membership
ID_00104 ID_00136 ID_00169 ID_00178 ID_00180 ID_06663 ID_06791 ID_09099 ID_00910 ID_00790 ID_01013 ID_01130 ID_01260 ID_00394 ID_00860 ID_00959 ID_01222 ID_00288 ID_00324 ID_00663 ID_00846 ID_01047 ID_06781 ID_06786 
       1        2        2        3        4        1        1        1        2        3        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4        4 

$csize
[1]  4  3  2 15

$no
[1] 4
```

I can also get the number of `degree` of a node using the below code

```
degree(graph1)
```

and the output is

```
ID_00104 ID_00136 ID_00169 ID_00178 ID_00180 ID_06663 ID_06791 ID_09099 ID_00910 ID_00790 ID_01013 ID_01130 ID_01260 ID_00394 ID_00860 ID_00959 ID_01222 ID_00288 ID_00324 ID_00663 ID_00846 ID_01047 ID_06781 ID_06786 
       3        2        2        1       14        1        1        1        2        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

I can add all components (randomly choosing 2 nodes from 2 components) using the below code (solution from one of my previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66826023/how-to-add-a-edges-between-component-of-a-graph-in-igraph-r))

```
graph1 <-  graph_from_data_frame(g, directed = FALSE)
E(graph1)$weight <- g$values
cl <- components(graph1)
graph2 <- with(
  stack(membership(cl)),
  add.edges(
    graph1,
    c(combn(sapply(split(ind, values), sample, size = 1), 2)),
    weight = 0.01))
```

Now, I want to add an `edge` between those `nodes` that have the highest number of `degree` e.g: `ID_00180` has degree `14` (left side component of the attached image) and `ID_00104` has degree `3` (the top component of the attached image). At the time of combining these 2 components, I want to add an edge between `ID_00180` and `ID_00104` ***(instead of taking randomly)***.

If any components have multiple same numbers of highest degree e.g: the right bottom components of the attached image (all nodes have degree 2) then we can take anyone randomly from the highest degree node. Say, we can add an edge between `ID_00180` and `any nodes`

Reproducible Data

```
g <- structure(list(query = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                        5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ID_00104", 
                                                                                                            "ID_00136", "ID_00169", "ID_00178", "ID_00180"), class = "factor"), 
                    target = structure(c(16L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 
                                         13L, 15L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 17L, 18L
                    ), .Label = c("ID_00169", "ID_00288", "ID_00324", "ID_00394", 
                                  "ID_00663", "ID_00790", "ID_00846", "ID_00860", "ID_00910", "ID_00959", 
                                  "ID_01013", "ID_01047", "ID_01130", "ID_01222", "ID_01260", "ID_06663", 
                                  "ID_06781", "ID_06786", "ID_06791", "ID_09099"), class = "factor"), 
                    values = c(0.654172560113154, 0.919096895578551, 0.925821596244131, 
                                0.860406091370558, 0.746376811594203, 0.767195767195767, 
                                0.830379746835443, 0.661577608142494, 0.707520891364902, 
                                0.908193484698914, 0.657118786857624, 0.687664041994751, 
                                0.68586387434555, 0.874513618677043, 0.836646499567848, 0.618361836183618, 
                                0.684163701067616, 0.914728682170543, 0.876297577854671, 
                                0.732707087959009, 0.773116438356164)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                      -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

```
graph2 <- add.edges(
  graph1,
  combn(
    sapply(
      decompose(graph1),
      function(p) sample(names(V(p))[degree(p) == max(degree(p))], 1)
    ), 2
  ),
  weight = 0.01
)

plot(graph2, layout = layout_nicely(graph1))
```

gives

[image]

---

## Previous Answer

You can try

```
out <- combn(
  decompose(graph1),
  2,
  FUN = function(x) {
    add.edges(
      graph1,
      sapply(x, function(p) sample(names(V(p))[degree(p) == max(degree(p))], 1)),
      weight = 0.01
    )
  },
  simplify = FALSE
)

sapply(out,plot)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. But, I need only one graph which will contain all combinations in one graph (e.g: the `graph2` object of my question code contains 6 combinations. I think your code is giving me the maximum node connection for separate separate graphs! Would you mind checking the code?

Comment: @0Knowledge See my update

Answer (score 3):

```
## Save the layout from graph1
set.seed(2021)
LO = layout_nicely(graph1)
plot(graph1, layout=LO)

MaxNode <- rep("", max(cl$membership))
for(i in 1:max(cl$membership)) {
    MaxNode[i] <- names(which.max(degree(graph1)[cl$membership == i])) 
}
graph2 <-add.edges(graph1, combn(MaxNode, 2), weight = 0.01)
plot(graph2, layout=LO)
```

[image: Graph with extra edges]